# image upload is not working in php

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm doing my project in bootstrap. there is an option for image upload in it, but i cant upload it in to my database.

boot.html:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="imgu">Upload images if / any</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input id="file" name="file" class="input-file" type="file">
  </div>
```

php file:

```
<?php
$a=$_POST['cname'];
$b=$_POST['subject'];
$c=$_POST['cat'];
$d=$_POST['cmp'];
$e=$_POST['cweb'];

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$x=$_FILES["file"]["name"];

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("com");
$sql=mysql_query("insert into cd values('$a','$b','$c','$d','$e','$x')");

if(!$sql)
{
echo "not Inserted";
}
else
{
header("location:home.php");
}
?>
```

If there any mistakes with this code please do help me

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute in your form tag :

> enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Your code looks fine, you must need to check your form `encoding` type either set or not, if not than follow this:

For input type file, you need to use `enctype` in your form as `multipart`.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
// your form fields
</form>
```

Form provided you three methods for encoding:

> 1. application/x-www-form-urlencoded (its default method)
> 2. multipart/form-data (use when you are using input=file)
> 3. text/plain (it will return you result as **key1=value1&key2=value2**)

Answer (score 0):

Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to form

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="imgu">Upload images if / any</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input id="file" name="file" class="input-file" type="file">
  </div>
</form>
```